# How to register for Desktop sharing events in UCMA 4.0

Tags: ucma

I have an UCMA 4.0 bot that handles IM calls. I need to have it handle any desktop sharing events from the Lync client and send a non-supported message back to the client.

I am assuming I need to register for the sharing request but how?

Answer (score 0):

If the bot doesn't support a particular modality it should report this back to the client in the form of a warning, please see the screen shot below for an example.

[image: Not supported in the client]

If you absolutely have to send an IM to report this then create a registration for incoming application sharing calls when you discover the application endpoint in much the same way as you would when registering to handle IM calls.  For example:-

```
 _endpoint.RegisterForIncomingCall<ApplicationSharingCall>((o, args) =>
            {
                //do stuff
            });
```

Comment: thanks Paul. That was what I'm looking for. I didn't know what to register for to trap the request. I'll try that.